# PostgreSQL 12.8 Same Query Same Execution Plan Different Time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I ran 2 same queries on PostgreSQL 12.8 machine running in AWS RDS, the first time I ran the query

the query plan was:

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=455652.07..455664.99 rows=340 width=16) (actual time=124047.119..124048.777 rows=294 loops=1)
   Group Key: dvh.history_date
   ->  Sort  (cost=455652.07..455655.24 rows=1269 width=8) (actual time=124046.989..124047.857 rows=7780 loops=1)
         Sort Key: dvh.history_date
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 557kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=13708.92..455586.66 rows=1269 width=8) (actual time=12.228..124039.597 rows=7780 loops=1)
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=13708.35..13746.45 rows=3810 width=4) (actual time=12.210..21.629 rows=6119 loops=1)
                     Group Key: pdv.id
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..13698.83 rows=3810 width=4) (actual time=0.038..10.650 rows=6119 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using idx_pc_device_acct_num on pc_devices  (cost=0.42..565.32 rows=506 width=4) (actual time=0.014..0.193 rows=396 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((account_number)::text = 'AB32823833'::text)
                           ->  Index Scan using pdv_uindex on pdv  (cost=0.42..25.73 rows=23 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.024 rows=15 loops=396)
                                 Index Cond: (pc_device_id = pc_devices.id)
               ->  Index Scan using idx_pc_dvh_dvh_id on pdv_history dvh  (cost=0.57..115.96 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.342..20.265 rows=1 loops=6119)
                     Index Cond: (pdv_id = pdv.id)
                     Filter: (status_changed AND (status_id = 1))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 187
 Planning Time: 1.050 ms
 Execution Time: 124048.850 ms
```

After that, I reran the same query again. The plan is basically the same:

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=455652.07..455664.99 rows=340 width=16) (actual time=12180.624..12182.286 rows=294 loops=1)
   Group Key: dvh.history_date
   ->  Sort  (cost=455652.07..455655.24 rows=1269 width=8) (actual time=12180.493..12181.363 rows=7780 loops=1)
         Sort Key: dvh.history_date
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 557kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=13708.92..455586.66 rows=1269 width=8) (actual time=1709.341..12177.249 rows=7780 loops=1)
               ->  HashAggregate  (cost=13708.35..13746.45 rows=3810 width=4) (actual time=1709.319..1713.171 rows=6119 loops=1)
                     Group Key: pdv.id
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.84..13698.83 rows=3810 width=4) (actual time=0.379..1706.606 rows=6119 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using idx_pc_device_acct_num on pc_devices  (cost=0.42..565.32 rows=506 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.279 rows=396 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((account_number)::text = 'AB32823833'::text)
                           ->  Index Scan using pdv_uindex on pdv  (cost=0.42..25.73 rows=23 width=8) (actual time=0.289..4.306 rows=15 loops=396)
                                 Index Cond: (pc_device_id = pc_devices.id)
               ->  Index Scan using idx_pc_dvh_dvh_id on pdv_history dvh  (cost=0.57..115.96 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.063..1.709 rows=1 loops=6119)
                     Index Cond: (pdv_id = pdv.id)
                     Filter: (status_changed AND (status_id = 1))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 187
 Planning Time: 1.262 ms
 Execution Time: 12182.361 ms
```

But the gap in the execution time between the two same queries is quite huge : 2 minutes vs 12 seconds.

I noticed that different is actually in `Nested Loop` join. One is taking 2 minutes, other is taking 12 seconds. I find this puzzling as I assume the nested loop should be done in memory.

The disk is `gp2 SDD` so I'm even more baffled by this. What could be the factors that affect the speed of nested loop. I notice for that both loops the `rows` is 7780 and `loops` is 1. I don't think those are big numbers

It was only after the running the 2 queries that I realize I could do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, but I couldn't reproduce the slowness.

Below are other information that might be relevant:

- The database has been vacuum analyzed before running the queries
- Platform : AWS RDS
- PG version : 12.8
- effective_cache_size : 7.9 GB (7935800kB)
- shared_buffers : 3.9 GB (3967896kB)
- work_mem : 64MB
- random_page_cost : 1.1
- Instance type : db.m6g.xlarge (4 vCPUs / 32 GB RAM)
- Database is idle. I'm the only one running the query
- version :  PostgreSQL 12.8 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6), 64-bit

Thanks.

Comment: Cache.  SSD may be fast but is still much slower then RAM.

Comment: @jjanes. If I understand correctly, the data has be in memory before the nested loop can be be performed.